# IntelliJ IDEA task integration with github

Tags: github, intellij-idea, task, issue-tracking

Has anyone successful made this work? I've followed the directions carefully, but I can't get my IDEA tasks to sync up with my issues list on github.  In the project setup I have the cache enabled to sync issues every five minutes, and in the server configuration when i hit "test" the connection is successful.  Does this feature actually work?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**I've managed to get it to work**

Here are the steps required in Intellij:

1. Settings | Tasks | Servers...
2. Add server with following details

- Username = GitHub user name
- Password = GitHub password
- Repository author = GitHub user name
- Repository = Name of project (e.g. "MultiBitMerchant")

3. Click Test

If all is well you'll get success, failure is usually a 401 and means you've added something strange into the above.

To check that you are synchronizing against your Issues, create an Issue on GitHub if you haven't already.

1. In Intellij, select Tools | Tasks and Contexts | Open task ...
2. Use CTRL + Space (or equivalent) to get list of tasks
3. Choose one then click OK
4. Make your changes in accordance with the task (stay focused on its requirement)
5. Commit (and push) to see your Issue reference placed as a commit comment for easy tracking

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it's the <control> + <space> part that I was missing.  Apparently this is required to get it to show up. I was expecting it to show up under existing tasks using the drop down in the toolbar.

Comment: I have the same problem as OP in 13.1.5. I pressed Ctrl+Space several times and no task is showing up. Is this feature broken in 13.1?

Comment: Not for me it isn't. I been work with GitHub issues as tasks in 13.1 every day. When selecting I tend to type the issue number to locate it.

Comment: Thanks this was helpful, can you create issues in github from IDEA?